# quickly check package exists using tlmgr on win command line

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

To check whether I have a certain package (say, placeins) installed in texlive 2017 using command line on windows. What is the right command to do so?

Comment: kpsewhich placeins.sty

Comment: ugh... I don't know whatever search terms I used, but I couldn't find that other question. Well, thanks gals and guys.